# selecting weighted random distribution from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, random, selection, weighted

i'm trying to write a query that will select a number of articles from a table randomly, but the articles have weighted chances to be chosen. i've come up with a solution, but it seems clumsy to me, and i was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to do it better. i need at least 1 article, but it would be helpful if the query returned several at once.

here is my approach :

the table --

```
mysql> describe randomiser;
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| article | varchar(30)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| chance  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
| low     | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| high    | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

my test population --

```
mysql> select * from randomiser;
+----+-------------+--------+-----+------+
| id | article     | chance | low | high |
+----+-------------+--------+-----+------+
|  1 | common      |    128 |   1 |  128 |
|  2 | uncommon    |     64 | 129 |  192 |
|  3 | infrequent1 |     32 | 193 |  224 |
|  4 | infrequent2 |     32 | 225 |  256 |
|  5 | infrequent3 |     32 | 257 |  288 |
+----+-------------+--------+-----+------+
```

the low and high values are updated on insert, any time someone adds a new article to the table.

my selection method --

```
SET @t:=(SELECT FLOOR( SUM(chance) * RAND() + 1) FROM randomiser);
SELECT article FROM randomiser WHERE @t >= low AND @t <= high;
```

1. is it possible to combine the selects into a single, efficient statement ?
2. is it possible to write a select that will pull several random values instead of only one ?

NOTE - i am not at all attached to the table as i've defined it ; if there's a different sort of layout so it will be more efficient, i would like to know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one query, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT article
FROM randomiser
WHERE (SELECT FLOOR( SUM(chance) * RAND() + 1) FROM randomiser) BETWEEN low AND high;
```

## SQLFiddle Demo

Or use `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT article, `range`
FROM randomiser
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        FLOOR( SUM(chance) * RAND() + 1) AS `range`
    FROM randomiser
) t
WHERE `range` >= low AND `range` <= high;
```

## SQLFiddle Demo

Comment: the first one does not seem to work. it will select the empty set and also two adjacent values. the second one seems to work quite well. :) thank you !   i suppose the only way to use it to fetch an arbitrary number of random articles would be to call it several times in a loop from the controlling program, right ? or do you think of some way it can get several random values ?

Comment: i suppose it can be done with multiple random 'range' values and assigning the names of the different output using `AS` in order to differentiate them after the fetch, but that also seems clumsy. i will have to think about this some more.

Comment: i was able to find a solution to the problem that returns multiple random articles by using a variant of the second approach (using inner join) and `union`. it is maybe not the best but it seems to perform well. thank you for the help !

Comment: @davidfurst Great, pleasure can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query

```
select t.article from
(SELECT article,
case when FLOOR( SUM(chance) * RAND() + 1) between low and high
         then 1 else 0 end as chance
FROM randomiser 
group by article) t
where t.chance = 1
```

the above one will use multiple random values

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. i get the following error: `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

Comment: @davidfurst i've changed the query

Comment: @davidfurst check now

Comment: it no longer gives the error, but instead it selects all values, sorted.

Comment: @davidfurst check now